# c# Setup Project Localization

Tags: c#, localization, setup-project

I have a desktop windows forms application written in c#, which has a setup up project. The setup project creates the setup in English. I want to make this setup wizard to be multilingual. I want my setup to ask the user which language to choose and it will continue in the language that the user chooses. I couldn't find a way to do in in visual studio 2008. What is the best way to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: just only setup wizard or entire project for multilingual....

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798886/c-sharp-creating-a-setup-for-multi-language

Comment: I have already made the application multilingual. The user can change the language from the interface. I want to localize just the setup project. @mekici That question is about deploying the multilingual project.  I want to make the installation wizard to be multilingual. Thanks.

Comment: I am using ORCA msi editor.(microsoft recommends ). No problem uptonow. But when a new version is built every change I made is gone :( besides this everything workds fine. You can have more information from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370557(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Ok I have solved the problem.In orca you can export and import the tables in the msi file. first create the msi then edit the tables in msi using orca. after that export all the tables in orca and create a backup for them. If you need to build the stup again you can import the table you have exported before and the setup again will be in your translated language.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at Infralutions Globalizer.NET product. It allows you to
localize the Setup (MSI) packages created by Visual Studio into any
language (not just the eight or so supported by Microsoft).

In  addition it can produce a `mulitlingual setup package` that will
     **automatically select the language to use based on the current locale
        of the user**

. It has a command line interface allowing it to be
integrated into your automated build process. You can get more
information and download an evaluation version from

http://www.infralution.com/globalizer.html

as per comments..i am hoping that this will helps you .....[setup and deplyment](http://vijirajkumar.blogspot.com/2010/03/create-setup-and-deployment-project.html) also...