# Visual studio installer project multi language support

Tags: c#, visual-studio, localization, windows-installer

I have a c# WPF application which is able to switch in deferent language as per customer wants. I also created a setup project for the same. I need to make the setup project also be able to switch language.
The problem is, the 'Visual studio installer project' doesn't have an option to do that. There is an option to set language for MSI. However dynamically changing the language is not supported

I have already googled it and no solution found.
some of the similar posts links are below. which also have no correct answer

[c# Setup Project Localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093785/c-sharp-setup-project-localization)

[How to create preview choosing setup language in Visual Studio Project Installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46661746/how-to-create-preview-choosing-setup-language-in-visual-studio-project-installer)

Any idea how to do that. Thanks in advance

Comment: [Some MSI tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130). Try to avoid localized setups if you can. Just install all files for all languages so there is one setup with complete QA. [This is not always possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546916/129130) (recommended read - maybe just download the language packs as you need them?). Installshield and Advanced Installer are the most complete products for MSI Deployment. WiX can do "anything" but features no GUI - it takes a while to learn and to manage.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience regarding this, but:

The Wix installer seems to have support for localization:
https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/

VDProject seems to be the right way to move forward aswell:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/buckh/visual-studio-setup-projects-vdproj-will-not-ship-with-future-versions-of-vs/

Comment: @sommmem - VDProject is still alive i think . see https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects.

Comment: @Ras sure - but it seems to be getting phased out

Comment: [Some problems with VDProjects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47944893/129130).