# VS2010 VC++ Setup Project misses language dll

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, dll, resources, installation

I have created a Setup Project in VS2010 for my VC++ project and I have it generating a setup file and it includes Primary Output, Content Files, Documentation files and Resource Sattelite DLLs from my VC++ project. My VC++ project is multilanguage and hence includes language DLL files in subdirectories. My issue is that the Setup Project does not include these language DLLs (nor their directories into which they must be placed).

I would have thought that these DLLs were included in the Project Output but they are not. :-/

I know I could add them manually by referencing the files directly, but that means including a absolute reference which I would rather not do. Also, a fixed reference means Release/Debug versions of the file are not handled (only one of them is use regardless of project setting).

Suggestions?

Edit: I have now tried Setup Project, InstallShield LE and WiX. None of them include the localization dll's into the setup project (only managed a working setup with Setup Project, but could see that the other installers did not include the required dll). I can't even fint any reference to this being a know bug and I have really tried hard to find a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Found it over there:

[C# Creating a setup for multi-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798886/c-sharp-creating-a-setup-for-multi-language)

It worked. I hope it is what you were searching for.

Comment: Unfortunately, the is no "Localized resources" in the Project Output section of the Setup project for VC++ projects. Maybe this is the actual problem I need to solve (VS2010 issue?).