# How to create preview choosing setup language in Visual Studio Project Installer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I try to create setup to my C# program. Program is multilang. I need to make preview choosing a lang for installer. I mean installer language. For Setup create i use Visual Studio Project Installer.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Creating a setup for multi-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798886/c-sharp-creating-a-setup-for-multi-language)

Comment: I've no idea what you mean by "prev" here.

Comment: @TAHATEMURII It\`s not duplicate, it\`s different. Please read a desription but not title.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever prev mean preview.